# node-inspector window is blank

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

Installed node-inspector via npm install -g nodeinspector.

I can get to the dashboard but it is just blank outside of a search bar.

I've tried starting the app/inspector/browser in all various orders and reinstalled node-inspector a couple times.  It was suggested to manually install the connect and async modules and I did, but to no avail.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: That image is so small; can't figure out which browser you are using

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install it with following command:

```
npm install -g node-inspector
```

Issue command in different command prompt:

```
node-inspector &
```

Run your program/app:

```
node --debug-brk your/short/node/script.js
```

Connect to `http://127.0.0.1:<PORT>/debug?port=5858` and you’re good to go!

Browse only in a WebKit based browser: Chrome, Safari to get the debugging option.

You can ref.: http://github.com/dannycoates/node-inspector/blob/master/readme.md

Answer (score 0):

I also met the blank page when i typed in firefox(10.0.11) with address `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858`.

But node-inspector works great after i changed to Chrome (version 23.0.1271.97).

Answer (score 0):

This happens usually when you have an add blocker, anti virus or similar program preventing the communication between inspector and chrome instance.

For me the issue was a download manager program which was supposed to takeover downloads from browser, once I killed it, inspector worked fine